# Visual studio 2022 Class library manage connected services does not show up

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-core, .net-core, visual-studio-2022

Class library manage connected services does not show

1- Open Visual studio 2022 enterprise

2- Creating a new Project as a core web API

2- add a new project Class library .net 5 or 6

4- right click on Debendansies to add WCF service

[image]

what I need is to add a WCF service to my project

Answer (score 14, accepted):

1- Right Click on The project itself

2- go to add => you will find Manage connected services

[image]